# Vega-Lite: "1 in X" custom legend labels

Tags: vega-lite, vega, observablehq

I'm working on a choropleth map that shows the share of the population that has confirmed positive case of Covid-19 in each political jurisdiction. Similar to this example in the per capita Mapbox graphic on [this page](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2020/us/missouri-coronavirus-cases.html#map) of the *The New York Times*.

I figured out just about every detail expect how to customize the legend. Currently, the labels display the `shareOfPop` as a number. Though, I want to prefix each label with "1 in ${shareOfPop}", and to add a suffix to the final label "1 in ${shareOfPop} or more".

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XBby.png).

I've created this map in an [Observable Notebook](https://observablehq.com/@mizzou-journalism/covid-19-cases-in-missouri-per-capita).

Things I've tried so far...

### Making us of the [custom legend encodings](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/legends/#custom)

To specify label text:

```js
vl.color()
  .fieldQ('shareOfPop')
  .scale(
    {
      scheme: "yelloworangered",
      domain: [250, 10],
      clamp: true,
    }
  )
  .legend({
    title: "Share of Pop.",
    encode: {
      labels: {text: "1 in ${datum.value}"}
    }
  })
```

### [Register a custom formatter](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/config.html#custom-format-type)

Which I doubt I've accomplished correctly.

Here's what my configuration looks like (which is based on the config in the [Introduction to Vega-Lite](https://observablehq.com/@uwdata/introduction-to-vega-lite#imports) notebook).

```js
vl = {
  const [vega, vegalite, api, tooltip] = await Promise.all([
    'vega@5.13.0',
    'vega-lite@4.14.1',
    'vega-lite-api@0.11.0',
    'vega-tooltip@0.22.1'
  ].map(module => require(module)));

  const options = {
    config: {
      // allow custom format types
      customFormatTypes: true,
      config: {
        view: {continuousWidth: 400, continuousHeight: 300},
        mark: {tooltip: null}
      }
    },
    init: view => {
      // initialize tooltip handler
      view.tooltip(new tooltip.Handler().call);
      // enable horizontal scrolling for large plots
      if (view.container()) view.container().style['overflow-x'] = 'auto';
      // register a custom expression function...am I doing this right???       
      vega.expressionFunction('1inX', function(datum) {
        return `1 in ${datum}`
      })
    },
    view: {
      // view constructor options
      loader: vega.loader({baseURL: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vega-datasets@1/'}),
      renderer: 'canvas'
    }
  };
  
  return api.register(vega, vegalite, options);
}
```

Then I specify this custom formatType when defining the mark:

```js
vl.color()
  .fieldQ('shareOfPop')
  .scale(
    {
      scheme: "yelloworangered",
      domain: [250, 10],
      clamp: true,
    }
  )
  .legend({
    title: "Share of Pop.",
    formatType: "1inX",
  })
)
```

Neither of these approaches produced any noticeable change.

Comment: You want to change the tooltip values or the legend? It looks like you already got your legend formatted the way you want, but the tooltip that displays on hover phrases it still as "Share of Pop: 164".

Answer (score 4):

Gonna answer my own question here.

Turns out Legend has a general `labelExpr` property that allows you to specify a [Vega expression](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/) for customizing the label.

In my case, I wanted to always prepend the string `"1 in "`, and also append `"+"` when over may domain limit. Here's how I did it using the [`join()`](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#join) and [`if()`](https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/expressions/#if) functions.

```js
...
vl.color()
  .legend(
    {
      labelExpr: "join(['1 in ', datum.value, if(datum.value >= 250, '+', '')], '')"
    }
  )
```

This property isn't documented for Legend, though it is for  [for Axis](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/axis.html#example-using-axis-labelexpr-to-display-initial-letters-of-month-name)).